# 70s-80s TV Show where an alien entity shaped as a small luminous pyramid gets in contact with a teenager

Tags: story-identification, tv

This was a TV Show that I've watched at early 80s in Spain, but the Show was english (I think I recall it being from BBC productions) so it could be perfectly produced on late 70s.

The show depicted a strange alien entity, shaped as a luminous pyramid which contacted with different teenagers along the show, but usually hided from their parents, teachers and other adults.

I don't recall exactly what was the purpose of the entity or its main objective, but I remember that the overall ambience of the show was a bit eerie and creepy (although that could be my perception, as I was just a child at the moment and maybe the intended target were older than me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're thinking of the BBC adaptation of *Chocky* by John Wyndham.

From [Wikipedia's description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocky_(TV_series)) of the first series:

> Matthew Gore is an intelligent boy chosen by a mysterious extraterrestrial visitor to be a source of information about life on Earth. As his schoolwork and artistic talent improve dramatically he arouses the suspicion of powerful groups who wish to tap into the amazing fund of knowledge to which he is now party.

The alien wasn't actually shaped like a pyramid, more a sort of shimmering light. But the theme sequence graphics did involve a pyramid, so that might be what you're thinking of. You can see it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LG1boSv80p4).

Comment: Yeah, that was it, I didn't remember much of the show as I was very young, but it was definitively this.